# Limit character length of copy and paste from website

Tags: javascript, html, copy-paste

Is it possible to limit the length of HTML text that can be copied from a website using JS? I've looked at some commercial products such as [Tynt](http://www.tynt.com/) but none seem to allow you to only permit the selection of say 200 characters?

Comment: Well you can get the current selection, and modify it … But what would be the purpose of this?

Comment: Someone with more dedication than me could probably hack something together with `user-select: none;` and the click event listener, but there must be another solution.

Comment: I want to prevent people from copying the entire content from the page and pasting it elsewhere. I only want them to copy 200 characters.

Comment: I see that you accepted my answer, for what its worth, you actually can't stop someone from copying your content. You are just slowing the average user down with Javascript solutions but not stopping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code cuts to first 200 characters, plus it also adds a read more link to what is copied.

```
document.body.oncopy = function () {
    var body_element = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var selection;
    selection = window.getSelection();
    var pagelink = "<br />Read more at: <a href='" + document.location.href + "'>" + document.location.href + "</a><br />";
    var copytext = selection.substring(0,200) + pagelink;
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    body_element.appendChild(newdiv);
    newdiv.innerHTML = copytext.substring(0,8);;
    selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        body_element.removeChild(newdiv);
    }, 0);
};
```

Comment: Are you [c.bavota](http://bavotasan.com/about/)? if not you should paste the [contents of the post](http://bavotasan.com/2010/add-a-copyright-notice-to-copied-text/) verbatim and give credit & a link instead of passing it off as your original work.

Comment: I apologize, it was actually something that I had saved in a library on my external drive, it has been so long I that I didn't have the source stored.

Comment: `substring()` can't be performed on `Selection` object ( `window.getSelection()` returns `Selection` object ). Need to use `selection.toString()`. Refer **notes** section here: [String representation of the Selection object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection)